# Argument isn't numeric

Tags: perl

I'm trying to accomplish a task which I did in another programming language, but Perl seems a bit different and I'm struggling.

I need to build a basic database and this database should hold the strings according to their first letter.

For example, when I give this input : `SQL AHT NFK IOS C64 SQL AHT END`

The desired output would be :

```
A – E: AHT C64 
F – J: IOS 
K – O: NFK 
P – T: SQL 
U – Z:
```

But when I give, for example, AAA BBB END, I get tons of errors and all of them are very similar:

```
Argument "AAA" isn't numeric in addition (+) at proje.pl line 76 <STDIN> line 3.
```

I'm putting all the code because I don't have any idea what is the reason of this error. I've checked other questions but I didn't help me a lot.

```
use warnings;

    sub doesExistInDatabase {

    my ($abbreviation) = @_;
    my @database = @_;
    my $boolean = 0;    

    for(my $c = 1; $c < 20; $c++){
        for(my $d = 0; $d < 5; $d++){
            if($database[$c][$d] eq ($abbreviation)){
                $boolean = 1;
            }
        }
    }
    return $boolean;
}

    $database[0][0] = "A-E";
    $database[0][1] = "F-J";
    $database[0][2] = "K-O";
    $database[0][3] = "P-T";
    $database[0][4] = "U-Z";

    for(my $i = 1; $i < 20; $i++){
        for(my $k = 0; $k < 5; $k++){
            $database[$i][$k] = "";
        }
    }

    @numberOfElements = (0,0,0,0,0);    

        while($numberOfElements[0] < 20 and $numberOfElements[1] < 20 and $numberOfElements[2] < 20
            and $numberOfElements[3] < 20 and $numberOfElements[4] < 20){

            my $abbreviation = <STDIN>; 
            chomp($abbreviation);
            my @chars = split //, $abbreviation;

            my $existing = doesExistInDatabase($abbreviation, @database);


            if($abbreviation eq "END"){
                last;
            }

            if($existing == 0){
                if($chars[0] eq "A" or $chars[0] eq "B" or $chars[0] eq "C" or 
                        $chars[0] eq "D" or $chars[0] eq "E"){
                    $numberOfElements[0]++;
                    $database[$numberOfElements[0]][0] = $abbreviation;
                }
                if($chars[0] eq "F" or $chars[0] eq "G" or $chars[0] eq "H" or 
                        $chars[0] eq "I" or $chars[0] eq "J"){
                    $numberOfElements[1]++;
                    $database[$numberOfElements[1]][0] = $abbreviation;
                }
                if($chars[0] eq "K" or $chars[0] eq "L" or $chars[0] eq "M" or 
                        $chars[0] eq "N" or $chars[0] eq "O"){
                    $numberOfElements[2]++;
                    $database[$numberOfElements[2]][0] = $abbreviation;
                }
                if($chars[0] eq "P" or $chars[0] eq "Q" or $chars[0] eq "R" or 
                        $chars[0] eq "S" or $chars[0] eq "T"){
                    $numberOfElements[3]++;
                    $database[$numberOfElements[3]][0] = $abbreviation;
                }
                if($chars[0] eq "U" or $chars[0] eq "V" or $chars[0] eq "W" or 
                        $chars[0] eq "X" or $chars[0] eq "Y" or $chars[0] eq "Z"){
                    $numberOfElements[4]++;
                    $database[$numberOfElements[4]][0] = $abbreviation;
                }
            }   
    }   
    print("\n$database[0][0]: ");
    for(my $x = 1; $x < $numberOfElements[0]+1; $x++){
        printf(" " + $database[$x][0]);
    }
    print("\n$database[0][1]: ");
    for(my $x = 1; $x < $numberOfElements[0]+1; $x++){
        printf(" " + $database[$x][1]);
    }
    print("\n$database[0][2]: ");
    for(my $x = 1; $x < $numberOfElements[0]+1; $x++){
        printf(" " + $database[$x][2]);
    }
    print("\n$database[0][3]: ");
    for(my $x = 1; $x < $numberOfElements[0]+1; $x++){
        printf(" " + $database[$x][3]);
    }
    print("\n$database[0][4]: ");
    for(my $x = 1; $x < $numberOfElements[0]+1; $x++){
        printf(" " + $database[$x][4]);
    }
```

Comment: You should start all Perl files with `use strict; use warnings;` to find many common problems automatically.

Comment: Don't use `printf` where `print` suffices. In particular, you need to have a very good reason to use `printf` with a non-constant format string.

Comment: The `+` operator adds two numbers.

Comment: USe `.` to concatenate strings, or just separate them with commas in `print " ", $database[$x][0], "\n";`

Comment: You should really use a hash for this. It will also be very fast !! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make your code a lot more readable and avoid those multidimensional arrays and C-style loops at the same time. A simple stringwise comparison is all you need in order to sift your terms into buckets:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use Data::Dump;

sub bucketize {
    my %buckets = (
        'A-E' => {},
        'F-J' => {},
        'K-O' => {},
        'P-T' => {},
        'U-Z' => {},
    );

    for my $term (@_) {    
        for my $bucket (reverse(sort(keys(%buckets)))) {
            if ($term gt $bucket) {
                $buckets{$bucket}{$term}++;
                last;
            }
        }
    }

    return \%buckets;
}

my $hash_ref = bucketize(qw(SQL AHT NFK IOS C64 SQL AHT));
dd($hash_ref);
```

Output:

```
{
  "A-E" => { AHT => 2, C64 => 1 },
  "F-J" => { IOS => 1 },
  "K-O" => { NFK => 1 },
  "P-T" => { SQL => 2 },
  "U-Z" => {},
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In perl the operator for string concatenation is . (period) not + (plus) which you have used:

```
printf(" " + $database[$x][0])
```

Should be:

```
printf(" " . $database[$x][0])
```

Or just:

```
print " $database[$x][0]"
```

When you have more knowledge of perl, maybe you'll want to take a look at this solution:

```
my(@group,%group) = qw(A-E F-J K-O P-T U-Z);
while(<>){
  my $abbr=$_; chomp($abbr);
  $group{$_}{$abbr}++ for grep $abbr=~/^[$_]/i, @group;
}
print "$_: ".join(" ",sort keys %{$group{$_}})."\n" for @group;
```

Test:

```
for i in SQL AHT NFK IOS C64 SQL AHT END AAA BBB END PERL;do echo $i;done|perl program.pl
A-E: AAA AHT BBB C64 END
F-J: IOS
K-O: NFK
P-T: PERL SQL
U-Z:
```